# How to deselect a map annotation on second tap

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkmapview

My task is to deselect a map annotatnion on second tap.

I didn't find how to do it with mapView functions. So I used an article from stackoverflow and do like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    annotationTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(annotationTapRecognized:)];
    annotationTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    annotationTap.delegate = self;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view addGestureRecognizer:annotationTap];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view removeGestureRecognizer:annotationTap];
}

- (void)annotationTapRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSArray *selectedAnnotations = self.viewMap.selectedAnnotations;
    for (MapAnnotation *annotationView in selectedAnnotations) {
        [self.viewMap deselectAnnotation:annotationView animated:NO];
    }
}
```

It seems works correct, but it is not. When I tap on the annotation second time callout disappears and appears again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found the solution. Maybe it's not good.

I've added boolean "is show", as luxsypher mentioned. So my functions looks like the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view addGestureRecognizer:annotationTap];

    if (isShow) {
        NSArray *selectedAnnotations = self.viewMap.selectedAnnotations;
        for (MapAnnotation *annotationView in selectedAnnotations) {
            [self.viewMap deselectAnnotation:annotationView animated:YES];
        }
        isShow = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)annotationTapRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSArray *selectedAnnotations = self.viewMap.selectedAnnotations;
    for (MapAnnotation *annotationView in selectedAnnotations) {
        [self.viewMap deselectAnnotation:annotationView animated:YES];
    }
    isShow = TRUE;
}
```

Maybe it will be useful for somebody :).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add a boolean "is visible" and act consequently. Cause it looks like you gesture is called and then "did Select" is called again.

Comment: But where have I add this? I thought about this. But how can I forbid displaying callout on click? Thanks.